# Strange header height

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

For some strange reason, the header has a height of 667. I have copy pasted the code from an example page. See screenshot:

[image]

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Left, Body, Right, Button, Icon, Title } from 'native-base';

export default class HeaderIconTextExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>
          <Left>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon style={{color:'white'}} name='menu' />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title style={{color:'white'}}>{this.props.headerText}</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon style={{color:'white'}} name='ios-add' />
            </Button>
          </Right>
        </Header>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to apply a height to the container (e.g. 100 pixels) but that does not change anything.

### Update

I have realised, that if I remove `ScrollView`, then the content is in the very top, in front of the header, like this:
[image]

Code:

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';

import {
    ScrollView, View
} from 'react-native';

import KeyDetail from './KeyDetail'

import axios from 'axios';

class KeyList extends Component {
    state = {
        keys: []
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
            .then(response => this.setState({ keys: response.data }));
    }

    renderKeys() {
        return this.state.keys.map(key => 
            <KeyDetail thekey={key} key={key.title} />
        );
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <ScrollView>
                { this.renderKeys() }
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}

export default KeyList;
```

### index.ios.js

```
/**
 * Import a library to help create a component
 */

    import React from 'react';

    import {
        AppRegistry,
        View
    } from 'react-native';

    import Header from './src/components/Header';
    import KeyList from './src/components/KeyList';

/**
 * Create a component
 */

    const App = () => (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Header headerText={'Your Keys'} />
            <KeyList />
        </View>
    );

/**
 * Render to device
 */

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('myapp', () => App);
```

Comment: share your css...

Comment: Could you share the component where `HeaderIconTextExample` is being rendered?

Comment: Plz update your question. Its incomplete. Need more info.

Comment: What info would you like?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. The solution (although not as pretty), is to wrap `KeyList` in `index.ios.js` inside a `View`, and then add marginBottom to prevent content from floating inside header.

index.ios.js

```
/**
 * Import a library to help create a component
 */

    import React from 'react';

    import {
        AppRegistry,
        View
    } from 'react-native';

    import Header from './src/components/Header';
    import KeyList from './src/components/KeyList';

/**
 * Create a component
 */

    const App = () => (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

            <Header headerText={'Your Keys'} />

            <View>
                <KeyList />
            </View>
        </View>
    );

/**
 * Render to device
 */

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('uniqkey', () => App);
```

Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Left, Body, Right, Button, Icon, Title } from 'native-base';

export default class HeaderIconTextExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={{marginBottom:64}}>
        <Header style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>
          <Left>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon style={{color:'white'}} name='menu' />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title style={{color:'white'}}>{this.props.headerText}</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon style={{color:'white'}} name='ios-add' />
            </Button>
          </Right>
        </Header>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `HeaderIconTextExample` component you haven't specify the `height` for the header. Add this style in HeaderIconTextExample component.

```
const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 60,
    paddingTop: 15,
 },
});
const { viewStyle } = Styles;
```

**Update this line:**

```
<Header style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>
```

**to this:**

```
<Header style={viewStyle}>
```

It will work fine.

You can check [my complete github repo code](https://github.com/Balasnest/Albums-react-native/blob/master/src/components/Header.js) of this Albums react native App.